# What is the name of the dotted line that shows the predicted turn radius, found on the Navigation display of the 738

Tags: boeing-737, navigation, flight-instruments

What is the name for the white dotted line that stretches out from the aircraft on the navigation display, when the aircraft enters a turn? It shows the aircrafts predicted flight path.

Comment: Do you have an image?

Answer (score 6):

The segmented white line is called the “Position Trend Vector”.

[image]

[image]

[image]